# "Like", "Dislike" plugin for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there any "like" , "dislike" plugin for rails...

I went through rating plugins... but all of them were 5 star rating plugins...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recommend creating the `like` and `dislike` option by taking on the classic vote model functionality.

So you have `Vote` as a join table between the `User` and the `Votable Item` .

A Vote value can work as Vote.value + 1 = Like, Vote.value -1 = Dislike, Vote.value = Neutral/Didn't vote.

Your controller for your votable item can look like this :

```
def like
  get_vote
  @vote.value += 1 unless @vote.value == 1
  @vote.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js 
  end
end

def dislike
  get_vote
  @vote.value -= 1 unless @vote.value == -1
  @vote.save
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js 
  end
end

private

def get_vote
  current_item = @item.detect{|r| r.id == params[:id].to_i}
  @vote = current_item.votes.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  unless @vote
    @vote = Vote.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :value => 0)
    current_item.votes << @vote
  end
end
```

And for everyone's info, this question didn't deserve to be voted down. Its completely valid.

Answer (score 5):

I know an answer has already been accepted but I've just found a gem called [act_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) that might fit your needs:

> Acts As Votable is a Ruby Gem specifically written for Rails/ActiveRecord models. The main goals of this gem are:
>
> - Allow any model to be voted on, like/dislike, upvote/downvote, etc.
> - Allow any model to vote. In other words, votes do not have to come from a user, they can come from any model (such as a Group or Team).
> - Provide an easy to write/read syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Try Recommendable:

https://github.com/davidcelis/recommendable

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing wrong with the question.

Up down voting is still rating. Just using only two stars. :) I seem to remember acts_as_rateable allowing number of star definition.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't just create a new boolean field named `like`? and then update it as `false` for *dislike* and `true` for *like*. I doubt you find a plugin/gem for this functionality.

Comment: Where would this boolean field go?

Comment: Umm, yeah... My point is it wouldn't be a case of adding a boolean field to an existing table as suggested. A join table would be required with the user_id, likeable_id, optionally polymorphic likeable_type, and boolean field.