# Adding a "Like/Unlike" button to a post in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The site is a simple community where each user creates posts and users may "like" them or "unlike" them.

I have a Post and a Like model. Currently, I'm listing all posts and also the likes size for each post through post.likes.size . The button to like a post is also working.

What i don't know how to do is how to depending on the case, if a post should show the unlike button or the like (depending if the current_user already liked that post).

The like model is very simple:

```
User_id // current user
Post_id // post to associate
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703194/like-dislike-plugin-for-rails/3703360#3703360

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define association in user model

if it's ror 2.* add  method in User model. it should look like this:

```
has_many :likes
def already_likes?(post)
  self.likes.find(:all, :conditions => ['post_id = ?', post.id]).size > 0
end
```

Assuming Like has fields user_id and post_id
and of course in view

```
if current_user.already_likes?(@post)
  #add unlike button
end
```

Comment: Really simple and great solution. This is the one I went for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You want to search for a record that matches the user_id and post_id. If you find one, you want to show the 'unlike' button, b/c that means the user has 'liked' the post already. If you don't (it returns nil), you want to show the 'like' button.

The following method returns nil if the user hasn't 'liked' the post, and not nil if the user has 'liked' the post.

```
def user_likes(current_user, post_id)
  likes.find(:first, :conditions => ['user_id = ? AND post_id = ?', current_user, post_id] ).nil?
end
```

So you can say:

```
if user_likes(1, 12).nil?
  # show like button
else
  #show unlike button
end
```

Comment: That was really simple and great! Thank you very much. Sorry for late answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also you could add validation to your Like model like so:

```
validate :user_does_not_already_like_post

def user_does_not_already_like_post
  errors.add(:user, "You can only like a post once.") if user.already_likes?(post)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

create an action like this in your posts controller.

```
def unlike
   # get the post
   #code to decrement the like counter of a specific post
end
```

then from your view, create a button or a link that points to this action.

Comment: I know that, but before showing the unlike button how do i know if I already liked it?