# rails relationship model ( like/unlike button)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreign-keys

I am trying to create and implement a `like/unlike` button to a post model in rails. The only thing I sort of understand is I need some sort of relationship model with a `has_many_through` association. can any one point me in the right direction to create this. I will prefer to create it from scratch to full understand it. thanks

Comment: you need to tell us what you've already done. we can help in any difficulty you've encountered but you need to let us know that you've really done something first :)

Comment: @joshua, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703194/like-dislike-plugin-for-rails

Comment: @sameera207 thanks alot!!!! didn't even think about taking that route to implement it. just what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems like you have a Person model. And you have a Post model. That Person model can be related to a Post model through something like an Opinion model (ugh... I hate trying to name relational models -- but the only thing I despise more would be a PersonPost model -- its not a PersonPost -- the person making the vote up or down isn't the poster - but enough of that). Opinion has a person_id and a post_id (and whatever other fields you think are useful).

So
Person
  has_many :opinions
  has_many :posts, :through => :opinions

Opinion
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :post

Post
  has_many :opinions
  has_many :people, :through => :opinions

Extend from there.

Comment: Ok, i see where you are coming from. Thanks, will try and extend.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908853/adding-a-like-unlike-button-to-a-post-in-rails) helps you alot. Create a new model called `Like` and relationship with `Post`

```
has_many :likes
```

One more [Simple like/unlike button with rails 3, jquery, and ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482354/simple-like-unlike-button-with-rails-3-jquery-and-ajax)

Comment: Thanks alot, that example app helps a great deal.