# How i can make dislike vote against a post using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Friends i have controller with the name of shops and i have did likes and unlike option against a post.Now i want to make a third option for dislike.The purpose is that i want to show down voting.I am using rails 4 version and here below my code.Kindly help me as i dont know how to figure out my problem.

Comment: Could you explain some more about what is going wrong for you?

Comment: i dont know how to write function in shops controller for dislike.

Comment: I have a status field in shoplikes table. I want to update this status filed 1 when like and -1 for dislike and by default it is 0. Now i want that there should be single field which should be updated according to user like, dislike .As in my code i am just counting likes but i also want to count dislike.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to start from scratch with a common Voting model. In your code above you have written only a controller and a view, but you need also a model.

Basically you need a Vote model and a controller with like, dislike and get_vote methods.
And don't forget to join the votes, users and voteable items.

For a hint how you could implement this, you can also see here: ["Like", "Dislike" plugin for rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703194/like-dislike-plugin-for-rails)